# Conditional densities and known past values

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, recursion, time-series

> Let there be a random variable with the following properties
>
> $Y_{t} = \mu + \beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} \quad\text{such that} \quad \epsilon_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$
>
> Estimate the parameters by the maximum likelihood method.

My doubt per se isn't about the inference part, I'm interested in one of the steps in-between. When computing the likelihood of a random sample $\{ X_{t} \}_{t=1}^{N}$, we can expand the joint into a product of conditional densities as in

$f_{X_{1},...,X_{N}}=f_{X_{1}}f_{X_{2}|X_{1}}f_{X_{3}|X_{2},X_{1}}...f_{X_{N}|X_{N-1},...,X_{1}}$

and we know by definition that

$f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{X,Y}}{f_{Y}}$

However I see in some examples on the web that people simply take $Y_{t-1}=y_{t-1}$ as fixed and substitute in the equation to get the new mean $\mathbb{E}(Y_{t}|Y_{t-1}=y_{t-1})= \mu + \beta y_{t-1}$, instead of the regular $\frac{\mu}{1-\beta}$.

My question is a bit naive. When can we simply substitute like that (Is it correct?) and when do we calculate the conditional density by definition?

Comment: Hmm sounds like they are really computing $\mathbb{E}(Y_t | Y_{t-1}=y_{t-1}).$

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right, i forgot the conditional there, however, can we just do this and not calculate the density by hand?

Comment: Hmmm.. it’s not clear to me what your question is: are you asking how they were able to compute the conditional mean without first computing the conditional density?

Comment: Actually my question exactly was "How they compute the conditional density without computing it directly?", however I think what you said about the moments actually answer it as we're working with $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: I think therein lied my confusion. In what you quoted after “some examples...” no conditional density is ever computed. All they do is condition on the value $Y_{t-1}$ and then take the expectation of $Y_t$. Implicitly, yes, there’s a conditional density under the hood by definition but its not needed due to the form of $Y_t$ given.